# Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError:Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Here are my models : sensor.js

```
   'use strict';
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const Sensor = sequelize.define('Sensor', {
        sensorName: DataTypes.STRING,
        user: DataTypes.INTEGER
      }, {});
      Sensor.associate = function(models) {
        Sensor.hasMany(models.User, {
            foreignKey: 'user'
        })
      };
      return Sensor;
    };
```

user.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.belongsTo(models.Sensor, {
      foreignKey: 'user'
    })
  };
  return User;
};
```

While doing

```
Sensor.findAll({
  'raw':true,
  include: [{
    model: User
  }]
})
.then(function(result){
  console.log(result)
})
```

I'm getting the following error :

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: User is not associated to Sensor!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a column (`user`) with the same name as the object relationship which is likely causing a conflict. By default Sequelize will create the `userId` (or `user_id` depending on settings) column automatically and you don't need to include it in the `define()` or the association, whereas you are using `user` for the ID an relationship.

Use the `as` property to define `1:n` relationships as they are pluralized.

sensor.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Sensor = sequelize.define('Sensor', {
    sensorName: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  Sensor.associate = function(models) {
    Sensor.hasMany(models.User, { as: 'users' })
  };
  return Sensor;
};
```

user.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.belongsTo(models.Sensor)
  };
  return User;
};
```

query

```
Sensor.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: User,
    as: 'users,
  }],
})
```